# Russian dictionary for a word game

Tags: offline, dictionary

I want to make a word game based around Russian language (for reasons). I don't really know the language, but that shouldn't stop me as long as I have the right resources. For this game to work, I would need at least a Russian Scrabble dictionary. I'm not particularly looking for a piece of software (unless it is a ready to use JavaScript library), but rather a free resource that I can incorporate for offline use in the game.

In the past I used JMdict/EDICT Japanese-English dictionary for similar purpose, but I assume there might be no Russian-English equivalent. I also used a simple Polish Scrabble dictionary (that was basically a text file with the words separated by new line characters). Surly something like this must exist for Russian language as well?. I wasn't able to find anything myself. It might have be the fact google results are too localized, but more likely it's just me not knowing the language. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a Russian MySpell dictionary from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/myspell-ru/filelist) or [huntpell](http://hunspell.github.io/) format from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/hunspell-ru/) and there is a variety of packages to open them such as [Enchant](http://www.abisource.com/enchant/) or [pyEnchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/api/enchant.html).  There are also online descriptions of the hunspell format such as [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries) that should get you started.

Comment: I'll have to filter the names out (looks doable), but otherwise it's exactly what I needed. Thank you kindly.

Comment: It may be worth looking at the python nltk for filtering parts of speech.